# Dependency issues when trying to install 32-bit OpenGL libraries

Tags: package-management, wine, opengl

My system is a Lenovo Thinkpad T450s with integrated graphics. After an upgrade from Lubuntu 18.04 to 18.10 (I only learned after this upgrade that you're not supposed to do it), I'm having trouble running a GameMaker game in Wine, presumably due to a lack of a 32-bit libGL:

> 0009:err:wgl:init_opengl Failed to load libGL: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I think `libglx-mesa0:i386` might be the right package to install, but I'm getting some strange errors when trying to install it, which suggest screwed-up dependencies. I previously had some Intel drivers installed from a PPA, but I `ppa-purge`d it before the upgrade. What should I do now?

```
$ sudo apt install libglx-mesa0:i386

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglx-mesa0:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.75) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 18.2.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`sudo aptitude install libglx-mesa0:i386` prints:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386{ab} libdrm-intel1:i386{ab} libdrm-nouveau2:i386{ab} libdrm-radeon1:i386{ab} libdrm2:i386{ab} libedit2:i386{a} libelf1:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{ab} 
  libglapi-mesa:i386{ab} libglx-mesa0:i386{b} libllvm7:i386{ab} libpciaccess0:i386{a} libx11-xcb1:i386{a} libxcb-dri2-0:i386{a} libxcb-dri3-0:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a} 
  libxcb-present0:i386{a} libxcb-sync1:i386{a} libxdamage1:i386{a} libxshmfence1:i386{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 20 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.2 MB of archives. After unpacking 234 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm-nouveau2 : Breaks: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (!= 2.4.96+git1812190630.597725~oibaf~b) but 2.4.95-1 is to be installed
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-nouveau2 (!= 2.4.95-1) but 2.4.96+git1812190630.597725~oibaf~b is installed
 libllvm7 : Breaks: libllvm7:i386 (!= 1:7.0.1-1~oibaf~b) but 1:7-3 is to be installed
 libllvm7:i386 : Breaks: libllvm7 (!= 1:7-3) but 1:7.0.1-1~oibaf~b is installed
 libglapi-mesa : Breaks: libglapi-mesa:i386 (!= 19.0~git1812271930.6adbd9~oibaf~b) but 18.2.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Breaks: libglapi-mesa (!= 18.2.2-0ubuntu1) but 19.0~git1812271930.6adbd9~oibaf~b is installed
 libdrm-amdgpu1 : Breaks: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (!= 2.4.96+git1812190630.597725~oibaf~b) but 2.4.95-1 is to be installed
 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-amdgpu1 (!= 2.4.95-1) but 2.4.96+git1812190630.597725~oibaf~b is installed
 libdrm2 : Breaks: libdrm2:i386 (!= 2.4.96+git1812190630.597725~oibaf~b) but 2.4.95-1 is to be installed
 libdrm2:i386 : Breaks: libdrm2 (!= 2.4.95-1) but 2.4.96+git1812190630.597725~oibaf~b is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 19.0~git1812271930.6adbd9~oibaf~b) but 18.2.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 18.2.2-0ubuntu1) but 19.0~git1812271930.6adbd9~oibaf~b is installed
 libdrm-intel1 : Breaks: libdrm-intel1:i386 (!= 2.4.96+git1812190630.597725~oibaf~b) but 2.4.95-1 is to be installed
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-intel1 (!= 2.4.95-1) but 2.4.96+git1812190630.597725~oibaf~b is installed
 libdrm-radeon1 : Breaks: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (!= 2.4.96+git1812190630.597725~oibaf~b) but 2.4.95-1 is to be installed
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-radeon1 (!= 2.4.95-1) but 2.4.96+git1812190630.597725~oibaf~b is installed
 libglx-mesa0 : Breaks: libglx-mesa0:i386 (!= 19.0~git1812271930.6adbd9~oibaf~b) but 18.2.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libglx-mesa0:i386 : Breaks: libglx-mesa0 (!= 18.2.2-0ubuntu1) but 19.0~git1812271930.6adbd9~oibaf~b is installed
open: 48; closed: 2024; defer: 21; conflict: 30                                                                                                                                                .The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 [Not Installed]                
2)     libdrm-intel1:i386 [Not Installed]                 
3)     libdrm-nouveau2:i386 [Not Installed]               
4)     libdrm-radeon1:i386 [Not Installed]                
5)     libdrm2:i386 [Not Installed]                       
6)     libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 [Not Installed]               
7)     libglapi-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                 
8)     libglx-mesa0:i386 [Not Installed]                  
9)     libllvm7:i386 [Not Installed]                      



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Comment: Looks like you still have packages from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers).

Comment: @fkraiem That's the PPA in question, all right. If the `ppa-purge` didn't fix everything, what can I do now?

Comment: Maybe something went wrong when you used `ppa-purge`; I'd first try adding the PPA again and update everything, then `ppa-purge` again and be extra careful for warnings or errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fkraiem's suggestion in the comments—to re-add the PPA, update, upgrade, and finally `ppa-purge` it again—resolved the dependency issue. I was able to install `libglx-mesa0:i386`. That turned out not to provide `libGL.so`, but `libglvnd-dev:i386` did.